# React not loading data for Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, components

I have built a React component and I want to put data in it when the component loads but I constantly get the Array as empty. To my understanding if I have to put data in a component I should do so in ComponentDidMount method.

Below is my code.

```
var Home = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount(){
    console.log('component mount');
    var self = this;
    var str = "junk string";
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:9000/checkoutcart/data/",
      type : "get",
      data : {
        ajaxid: 4, 
        UserID: str
        },
    }).then(function (data) {    
      self.setState({movieItem: data});
    });
},

getInitialState: function() {   
    console.log('getInitialState component mount');
    return {movieItem:[]};
  },

  render: function() {
      return (
        <div>          

        <div>               
        <div>
        <ol>
            {this.state.movieItem.map(stuff => (
              <li><h4>{stuff.title}</h4></li>
            ))}
          </ol>
        </div>
        </div>


        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you check API response?

Comment: Try doing it without `var self = this;`

Comment: I'm just wondering why you are using this version of React?

Comment: @Liam : I am not sure about your comment ?? I am just trying out.

Comment: @Geek did u solve?

Comment: No dear. It seems I am unable to attach a Ajax response to any component. Something is wrong with my approach.

Comment: I mean you are using the old version, why not trying out the new version of react